# How to detect memory leak or other system-wide problems caused by a batch processing job?

Tags: windows, batch-file

**First the question:**

How do I monitor the complete flow of the batch file, including influences to the surrounding system, all the way from initiating the cmd.exe to tearing it down after the script has completed?

**Then the reason:**

I've recently set up a batch script job to extract data, pack the data and transfer the compressed file to an external storage. It's a massive job executing for about 10 hours, and using lots of disk space.

It's the only change to the system (Windows Server 2008 SE SP2, 32bit with 4GB RAM) in a very long time, and just a few minutes after running the full script the for the second time, **the server crashed hard**, and had to be power-cycled.

I've been going through the script's log file, and everything worked flawless - at least down to the last line in the script that outputs the last line in the log file. Then I checked systems event log files, and found nothing to indicate an eminent problem... But **I still very much suspect this script to be the triggering cause!** Perhaps some sort of memory leak or memory fragmentation could be involved?

**Finally the overall script operation and numbers:**

The data is extracted from database files (SubVersion) on one disk, and temporarily stored on another disk (in about 150.000 files of varying size, taking up about 250 GB of space), then combined into about 1000 files which are compressed with 7zip down to about 22GB, which is transferred to external storage. Finally, all temporary files are removed, with the exception of a log file.

The initial batch script calls several other batch scripts in the cause of processing the data, during the task described above other scripts or commands are called about 20.000 times. Total number of lines in the scripts are about 600, with several for loops involved.

Comment: I would start by testing with a much smaller database. You might make sure you have a corresponding POPD for every PUSHD and that there are no places where you might JUMP around a POPD... or for that matter, a place where you might jump into code that has a POPD for which there was no PUSHD.

Comment: 7zip can easily crash your server if its memory consumption is too high.

Comment: @RGuggisberg, I have already checked the code for those sorts of things. I've also been working on a smaller set of databases, and haven't noticed any problems. Even with the big set of databases, I found no direct problems: The execution continues to the end and performs what's expected.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks. I expect such a crash would happen during the curse of 7zip's operation, not several minutes after it's last run...